# java String to Date converstion for dd/MM/yy

Tags: java, date, format

How to convert this string to date?
5/14/15 and 
12/12/14

I have tried using for "dd/MM/yyyy" and "dd/MM/yy and they dont work

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: How to handle the year? I have 15 instead of 2015

Answer (score 4):

You've mixed up day & month

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: How to handle the year? I have 15 instead of 2015

Comment: This pattern will still work although  `MM/dd/yy` is clearer

Answer (score 2):

```
String dateString = "5/14/15";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

In your question, you have the dd and MM values in the incorrect places in the pattern string which is passed into SimpleDateFormat and you need to swap them.

As we can see from your dates that you want to convert, the month is before the day in your date string. Therefore MM must be before dd in the pattern string.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple format:-

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Some Helpfull stuff

// SimpleDateFormat can be used to control the date/time display format:
       //   E (day of week): 3E or fewer (in text xxx), >3E (in full text)
       //   M (month): M (in number), MM (in number with leading zero)
       //              3M: (in text xxx), >3M: (in full text full)
       //   h (hour): h, hh (with leading zero)
       //   m (minute)
       //   s (second)
       //   a (AM/PM)
       //   H (hour in 0 to 23)
       //   z (time zone)
```